# Aggregating firestore collectionGroups (e.g. find root document maximum)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use Firestore JavaScript v9.
I have a data structure of items with deeply nested tasks, like this:

- item A

  - task1

    - task1.1
  - task2
- item B

  - task1
  - task2

    - task2.1

      - task2.1.1

Every Task has an endDate Timestamp and a subcollection "subTasks".

How can I query the max / latest endDate of all subTasks within an item?

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal, reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, can you attach your Firebase collection so that the community can best assist you.

Comment: @RJC My main problem is: How to find the root document that the document belongs to. Right now I use a private api for this to get the path segemnts:

Below is an doc that i receive from the collectionGroup() call: 
doc["_key"].path.segments[6]

Comment: Please post the detailed structure of your Firebase [data model](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/data-model) so that the community can best assist you further.

Comment: The question is a bit vague as we don't know what kinds of queries you want or what you will run them against e.g. we don't know what you mean by *subtask* - is that task1, or task2.1? You should consider changing the structure; one option is to flatten it and have all tasks as documents within item A or item B. You can then query across all tasks. You can use the task number to know what tasks belong together. e.g. If you run a query and it returns task 2.1.1 you know that's a child of task 2.1 which is a child-child of task 2. Etc.